# Ubuntu 17.04 quits to terminal

Tags: 17.04, fsck

After upgrading to 17.04 yesterday,  everything ran okay until a morning reboot. 
Now I am getting the errors shown in the (how embarrassing) photo that's attached. 
Any help appreciated. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that particular shell.  Since it supports "help", type help and see if you get lucky and there is an option to run fsck on the unmounted root partition.  If not, you will need to boot from a liveCD and run fsck on it.

Note that if your hard drive is in good shape and you didn't shut the machine down by just removing the power, you should not be seeing these messages.  If you did an orderly shutdown last time, you'll want to run some basic disk drive diagnostics and look at the SMART info on the drive to verify that it's not on it's way out.